# Implementation of Yield in following ruby code

Tags: ruby, yield

I use and work on Java and C#. 
I was asked to explain Yield in following Ruby code.
**Code:**

```
mine=15
puts "Mine = 15"

def call_block  
   yield
   yield
puts 'Now for some magic!'  
end

call_block {mine}
print "Mine now is "
puts mine
```

**Output:**

```
mine = 15
now for some Magic!
mine now is 25
```

The question is how to get this output using the above code.
I don't know much about yield and that's why not getting the code right.
I think 10 has to be added somewhere but where?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read any online tutorials, or searched for "ruby yield"? What did you find? Why didn't they help?

Comment: I did a quick search on yield and what i understood was that it was just an imaginary call for whatever reason to be changed later.  I think the example i saw was they called yield and passed a variable with it and said its a place holder for later use?

Comment: Did you run the code? What does it produce? How might you change the output of `call_block` to accomplish the goal?

Comment: Think of `z = yield(x,y)` as `z = execute_block(x,y)` where `x` and `y` are values to be assigned to the block's two block variables and `z` is assigned the value computed and returned by the block.

Comment: `yield` is used (in one sense) in English as a verb meaning to _give way_ or _hand over_. In Ruby code we mean to yield to the block.

Comment: It's my understanding that Java has anonmymous functions. That's basically what yield is. You allow a function to take a _block of code_ as an argument not just a value. See [/ruby-proccall-vs-yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410160/ruby-proccall-vs-yield)

Answer (score -1):

Change `{mine}` to `{mine+=5}`. `yield` just executes it twice.

Comment: @sublimeaces Point of what? `yield` is a syntactic sugar for executing a function that was passed as an argument. The other syntax would be to list it as `def call_block(&block)` and then perform a `block.call` twice.

Comment: There is no point for it in your example, but consider a sort method that accepts a custom sorting algorithm: `[1,2,3].sort_by{ |i| -i }` will perform a reverse sort

Comment: or a mapping method that takes a custom function to apply to every element: `[1,2,3].map{ |i| i + 10 } # => [11,12,13]`

Comment: Under the hood it did something like: `[yield(1), yield(2), yield(3)]`