# Blocks and yields in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-block

I am trying to understand blocks and `yield` and how they work in Ruby.

How is `yield` used? Many of the Rails applications I've looked at use `yield` in a weird way.

Can someone explain to me or show me where to go to understand them?

Comment: You might be interested in the answer to [Ruby’s yield feature in relation to computer science](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764134/rubys-yield-feature-in-relation-to-computer-science/765126#765126). Though it's a somewhat different question than yours, it may shed some light on the matter.

Answer (score 422, accepted):

Yes, it is a bit puzzling at first.

In Ruby, methods can receive a code block in order to perform arbitrary segments of code.

When a method expects a block, you can invoke it by calling the `yield` function.

Example:

Take `Person`, a class with a `name` attribute and a `do_with_name` method. When the method is invoked it will pass the `name` attribute to the block.

```
class Person 
    def initialize( name ) 
         @name = name
    end

    def do_with_name   # expects a block
        yield( @name ) # invoke the block and pass the `@name` attribute
    end
end
```

Now you can invoke this method and pass an arbitrary code block.

```
person = Person.new("Oscar")

# Invoking the method passing a block to print the value
person.do_with_name do |value|
    puts "Got: #{value}"
end
```

Would print:

```
Got: Oscar
```

Notice the block receives as a parameter a variable called `value`.  When the code invokes `yield` it passes as argument the value of `@name`.

```
yield( @name )
```

The same method can be invoked with a different block.

For instance to reverse the name:

```
reversed_name = ""

# Invoke the method passing a different block
person.do_with_name do |value| 
    reversed_name = value.reverse
end

puts reversed_name

=> "racsO"
```

Other more interesting real life examples:

Filter elements in an array:

```
 days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]  

 # Select those which start with 'T' 
 days.select do | item |
     item.match /^T/
 end

=> ["Tuesday", "Thursday"]
```

Or sort by name length:

```
 days.sort do |x,y|
    x.size <=> y.size
 end

=> ["Monday", "Friday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday"]
```

If the block is optional you can use:

```
yield(value) if block_given?
```

If is not optional, just invoke it.

You can try these examples on your computer with `irb` ([Interactive Ruby Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell))

Here are all the examples in a copy/paste ready form:

```
class Person 
    def initialize( name ) 
         @name = name
    end

    def do_with_name   # expects a block
        yield( @name ) # invoke the block and pass the `@name` attribute
    end
end


person = Person.new("Oscar")

# Invoking the method passing a block to print the value
person.do_with_name do |value|
    puts "Got: #{value}"
end


reversed_name = ""

# Invoke the method passing a different block
person.do_with_name do |value| 
    reversed_name = value.reverse
end

puts reversed_name



# Filter elements in an array:    
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]  

# Select those which start with 'T' 
days.select do | item |
    item.match /^T/
end



# Sort by name length:     
days.sort do |x,y|
   x.size <=> y.size
end
```

Comment: how it prints `racsO` if  `the_name = ""`

Comment: Sorry, the name is an instance variable initialized with `"Oscar"`  ( is not very clear in the answer )

Comment: What about code like this? `person.do_with_name {|string| yield string, something_else }`

Comment: So in Javascripty terms, it's a standardized way of passing a callback to a given method, and calling it. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: In a more general way - a block is a ruby "enhanced" syntax sugar for Strategy pattern.

because typical usage is to provide a code to do something in context of other operation.

But ruby enhancements open a way to such cool things as writing DSLs using block to pass context around

Comment: Thanks @OscarRyz, I added a repl.it to help illustrate your great examples: https://repl.it/@makstaks/blocksandyieldsrubyexample

Answer (score 33):

In Ruby, methods can check to see if they were called in such a way that a block was provided in addition to the normal arguments.  Typically this is done using the `block_given?` method but you can also refer to the block as an explicit Proc by prefixing an ampersand (`&`) before the final argument name.

If a method is invoked with a block then the method can `yield` control to the block (call the block) with some arguments, if needed.  Consider this example method that demonstrates:

```
def foo(x)
  puts "OK: called as foo(#{x.inspect})"
  yield("A gift from foo!") if block_given?
end

foo(10)
# OK: called as foo(10)
foo(123) {|y| puts "BLOCK: #{y} How nice =)"}
# OK: called as foo(123)
# BLOCK: A gift from foo! How nice =)
```

Or, using the special block argument syntax:

```
def bar(x, &block)
  puts "OK: called as bar(#{x.inspect})"
  block.call("A gift from bar!") if block
end

bar(10)
# OK: called as bar(10)
bar(123) {|y| puts "BLOCK: #{y} How nice =)"}
# OK: called as bar(123)
# BLOCK: A gift from bar! How nice =)
```

Answer (score 24):

It's quite possible that someone will provide a truly detailed answer here, but I've always found [this post](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas) from Robert Sosinski to be a great explanation of the subtleties between blocks, procs & lambdas.

I should add that I believe the post I'm linking to is specific to ruby 1.8. Some things have changed in ruby 1.9, such as block variables being local to the block. In 1.8, you'd get something like the following:

```
>> a = "Hello"
=> "Hello"
>> 1.times { |a| a = "Goodbye" }
=> 1
>> a
=> "Goodbye"
```

Whereas 1.9 would give you:

```
>> a = "Hello"
=> "Hello"
>> 1.times { |a| a = "Goodbye" }
=> 1
>> a
=> "Hello"
```

I don't have 1.9 on this machine so the above might have an error in it.

Comment: Great description in that article, it took me months to figure that all out on my own =)

Comment: I agree. I don't think I knew half of the stuff explained until I read it.

Comment: The updated link is 404 now, too. Here's the [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20160324174007/http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas).

Answer (score 14):

I found [this article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm) to be very useful. In particular, the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def test
  yield 5
  puts "You are in the method test"
  yield 100
end

test {|i| puts "You are in the block #{i}"}

test do |i|
    puts "You are in the block #{i}"
end
```

which should give the following output:

```
You are in the block 5
You are in the method test
You are in the block 100
You are in the block 5
You are in the method test
You are in the block 100
```

So essentially each time a call is made to `yield` ruby will run the code in the `do` block or inside `{}`. If a parameter is provided to `yield` then this will be provided as a parameter to the `do` block.

For me, this was the first time that I understood really what the `do` blocks were doing. It is basically a way for the function to give access to internal data structures, be that for iteration or for configuration of the function.

So when in rails you write the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render template: "my/view", layout: 'my_layout' }
end
```

This will run the `respond_to` function which yields the `do` block with the (internal) `format` parameter. You then call the `.html` function on this internal variable which in turn yields the code block to run the `render` command. Note that `.html` will only yield if it is the file format requested. (technicality: these functions actually use `block.call` not `yield` as you can see from the [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to#source_link) but the functionality is essentially the same, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410160/ruby-proccall-vs-yield) for a discussion.) This provides a way for the function to perform some initialisation then take input from the calling code and then carry on processing if required.

Or put another way, it's similar to a function taking an anonymous function as an argument and then calling it in javascript.

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to sort of add why you would do things that way to the already great answers.

No idea what language you are coming from, but assuming it is a static language, this sort of thing will look familiar. This is how you read a file in java

```java
public class FileInput {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("C:\\MyFile.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);

      // Here BufferedInputStream is added for fast reading.
      bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

      // dis.available() returns 0 if the file does not have more lines.
      while (dis.available() != 0) {

      // this statement reads the line from the file and print it to
        // the console.
        System.out.println(dis.readLine());
      }

      // dispose all the resources after using them.
      fis.close();
      bis.close();
      dis.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Ignoring the whole stream chaining thing, The idea is this

1. Initialize resource that needs to be cleaned up
2. use resource
3. make sure to clean it up

This is how you do it in ruby

```
File.open("readfile.rb", "r") do |infile|
    while (line = infile.gets)
        puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
        counter = counter + 1
    end
end
```

Wildly different. Breaking this one down

1. tell the File class how to initialize the resource
2. tell the file class what to do with it
3. laugh at the java guys who are still typing ;-)

Here, instead of handling step one and two, you basically delegate that off into another class. As you can see, that dramatically brings down the amount of code you have to write, which makes things easier to read, and reduces the chances of things like memory leaks, or file locks not getting cleared.

Now, its not like you can't do something similar in java, in fact, people have been doing it for decades now. It's called the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java) pattern. The difference is that without blocks, for something simple like the file example, strategy becomes overkill due to the amount of classes and methods you need to write. With blocks, it is such a simple and elegant way of doing it, that it doesn't make any sense NOT to structure your code that way.

This isn't the only way blocks are used, but the others (like the Builder pattern, which you can see in the form_for api in rails) are similar enough that it should be obvious whats going on once you wrap your head around this. When you see blocks, its usually safe to assume that the method call is what you want to do, and the block is describing how you want to do it.

Comment: Let's simplify that a bit: `File.readlines("readfile.rb").each_with_index do |line, index| puts "#{index + 1}: #{line}" end` and laugh even harder at the Java guys.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, laugh after you read a file a couple of gigabytes long.

Comment: @akostadinov No... that makes me want to cry!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Or, better yet: `IO.foreach('readfile.rb').each_with_index { |line, index| puts "#{index}: #{line}" }` (plus no memory issues)

Answer (score 11):

In Ruby, a block is basically a chunk of code that can be passed to and executed by any method. Blocks are always used with methods, which usually feed data to them (as arguments).

Blocks are widely used in Ruby gems (including Rails) and in well-written Ruby code. They are not objects, hence cannot be assigned to variables.

### Basic Syntax

A block is a piece of code enclosed by { } or do..end. By convention, the curly brace syntax should be used for single-line blocks and the do..end syntax should be used for multi-line blocks.

```
{ # This is a single line block }

do
  # This is a multi-line block
end
```

Any method can receive a block as an implicit argument. A block is executed by the yield statement within a method. The basic syntax is:

```
def meditate
  print "Today we will practice zazen"
  yield # This indicates the method is expecting a block
end 

# We are passing a block as an argument to the meditate method
meditate { print " for 40 minutes." }

Output:
Today we will practice zazen for 40 minutes.
```

When the yield statement is reached, the meditate method yields control to the block, the code within the block is executed and control is returned to the method, which resumes execution immediately following the yield statement.

When a method contains a yield statement, it is expecting to receive a block at calling time. If a block is not provided, an exception will be thrown once the yield statement is reached. We can make the block optional and avoid an exception from being raised:

```
def meditate
  puts "Today we will practice zazen."
  yield if block_given? 
end meditate

Output:
Today we will practice zazen.
```

It is not possible to pass multiple blocks to a method. Each method can receive only one block.

See more at: http://www.zenruby.info/2016/04/introduction-to-blocks-in-ruby.html

Comment: This is the (only) answer that really makes me understand what is block and yield, and how to use them.

Answer (score 6):

I sometimes use "yield" like this:

```
def add_to_http
   "http://#{yield}"
end

puts add_to_http { "www.example.com" }
puts add_to_http { "www.victim.com"}
```

Comment: Ok, but why ? There are plenty of reasons, such as the one `Logger` has to not perform some task if the user don't need to. You should explain yours though...

Answer (score 4):

Yields, to put it simply, allow the method you create to take and call blocks.  The yield keyword specifically is the spot where the 'stuff' in the block will be performed.

Answer (score 3):

There are two points I want to make about yield here. First, while a lot of answers here talk about different ways to pass a block to a method which uses yield, let's also talk about the control flow. This is especially relevant since you can yield MULTIPLE times to a block. Let's take a look at an example:

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :kinds

  def initialize 
    @kinds = %w(orange apple pear banana)
  end

  def each 
    puts 'inside each'
    3.times { yield (@kinds.tap {|kinds| puts "selecting from #{kinds}"} ).sample }
  end  
end

f = Fruit.new
f.each do |kind|
  puts 'inside block'
end    

=> inside each
=> selecting from ["orange", "apple", "pear", "banana"]
=> inside block
=> selecting from ["orange", "apple", "pear", "banana"]
=> inside block
=> selecting from ["orange", "apple", "pear", "banana"]
=> inside block
```

When the each method is invoked, it executes line by line. Now when we get to the 3.times block, this block will be invoked 3 times. Each time it invokes yield. That yield is linked to the block associated with the method that called the each method. It is important to notice that each time yield is invoked, it returns control back to the block of the each method in client code. Once the block is finished executing, it returns back to the 3.times block. And this happens 3 times. So that block in client code is invoked on 3 separate occasions since yield is explicitly called 3 separate times.

My second point is about enum_for and yield. enum_for instantiates the Enumerator class and this Enumerator object also responds to yield.

```
class Fruit
  def initialize
    @kinds = %w(orange apple)
  end

  def kinds
    yield @kinds.shift
    yield @kinds.shift
  end
end

f = Fruit.new
enum = f.to_enum(:kinds)
enum.next
 => "orange" 
enum.next
 => "apple"
```

So notice every time we invoke kinds with the external iterator, it will invoke yield only once. The next time we call it, it will invoke the next yield and so on.

There's an interesting tidbit with regards to enum_for. The documentation online states the following:

```
enum_for(method = :each, *args) → enum
Creates a new Enumerator which will enumerate by calling method on obj, passing args if any.

str = "xyz"
enum = str.enum_for(:each_byte)
enum.each { |b| puts b }    
# => 120
# => 121
# => 122
```

If you do not specify a symbol as an argument to enum_for, ruby will hook the enumerator to the receiver's each method. Some classes do not have an each method, like the String class.

```
str = "I like fruit"
enum = str.to_enum
enum.next
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "I like fruit":String
```

Thus, in the case of some objects invoked with enum_for, you must be explicit as to what your enumerating method will be.

Answer (score 0):

**Yield** can be used as nameless block to return a value in the method. Consider the following code:

```
Def Up(anarg)
  yield(anarg)
end
```

You can create a method "Up" which is assigned one argument. You can now assign this argument to yield which will call and execute an associated block. You can assign the block after the parameter list.

```
Up("Here is a string"){|x| x.reverse!; puts(x)}
```

When the Up method calls yield, with an argument, it is passed to the block variable to process the request.