# Using ruby blocks with method calls

Tags: ruby, block, hpricot

The following code works perfectly.

```
@doc = open(link) { |f| Hpricot(f) }
```

But I want to use the following code, which doesn't seem to play well with the Hpricot block (e.g. @doc is a TempFile object, not a Hpricot document object)

```
@doc = resolve_link(link) { |f| Hpricot(f) }

def resolve_link(link)
  begin
    return open(link)
  rescue
    logger.debug("#{$!} for link #{link}")
    raise Exceptions::ErrorResolvingLink.new("Cannot resolve link #{link}.")
  end
end
```

Any idea how I can get the second version of the code to work?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but you can omit `begin` and `end` leaving `rescue` in immediate environment of `def`.

Comment: @sawa: OTOH, the `begin` is a nice visual marker that you're about to do some exception handling and the reader should pay attention.

Comment: @mu is too short I usually bring `rescue` at the same indent level as `def` and its corresponding `end`, so `rescue` outstands enough. Whenever you meet `rescue`, you can tell that whatever beyond is error handeling.

Comment: @sawa: It is really a question of style (and hence personal preference), I just find that it is clearer to be warned that something is about to happen before it happens rather than being told afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `resolve_link` with a block but you're not passing that block down to `open`. Try this instead:

```
def resolve_link(link, &block)
  begin
    return open(link, &block)
  #...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  `yield` to invoke the block.

See this answer for a very simple example:

[Blocks and yields in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby/3066939#3066939)

So something along the lines

```
def resolve_link(link)
    ...
    yield ( some_value_to_pass_to_the_block )
    ...
end
```

Should work.