# In ruby how do I write a 'do' method in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

I keep writing the same pattern of code in Ruby, which seems like it would benefit from a 'do' style bit of code but I'm not sure how to write the method.

I keep doing this pattern of code, which starts and ends with the same lines of code...

```
x.increment!(:step_count) # same each time
# ...then some different code each
x.update_column(:step_description, "blerg message") # same each time
```

I feel it would benefit from a 'do' something that would look like this...

```
update_steps "blerg message" do
    # ...then some different code each
end
```

And then inside the 'do' each time it does the common code.

How would I go about making a method where I can use a 'do'.

Thanks!

Edit: I think it's important to not close this because I didn't know to search for 'block' or 'yield'. People who may no know these terms may end up searching for 'do' instead.

Comment: It's called a "block" and the `yield` keyword is the active ingredient. This should help: [Blocks and Yields in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby)

Comment: "_because I didn't know to search for 'block' or 'yield'_"  The closure won't become a deletion. Instead, your suggestion that others might search for "do" instead is exactly the reason to close it. Doing so will link it to a question with the right terminology, already having several complete and highly upvoted answers.  The closure isn't a bad thing in this case, especially since you're still getting answers relevant to your use case, but it will direct future searchers to other relevant answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass it a block as an argument

```
    def my_method(&block)
        do_something_the_same
        yield # calls whatever is inbetween "do" and "end"
    end
```

Comment: You don't need to specify `&block` argument explicitly if you use `yield` keyword.

Comment: How do you take into account the other string param too, so I want to pass in a string and then the block?

Comment: @Smickie you can pass arguments into `yield` in regular way, for example `yield(str)`.

Answer (score 10):

Creating methods that accept a block is one of Ruby's most powerful features.

The common way to define such a method would be:

```
def foo(*args, &block)
  # your code here
  yield
  # some more code
end

foo do
  # This code runs when yield is called 
end
```

There are a few things you should know about the above:

1. The `&block` parameter is not required. You can just use `yield` anyway. But there are a few reasons why you should add it to your method definition:

   - It makes it clear that your method accepts a block
   - The `&` basically transforms the block to a `proc` object. This could be handy since that way you can actually pass it around as a parameter to another method that accepts a block. You just need to re-apply the `&` to make it again a block.
   - Handling a `proc` object can be more powerful since you can also set its binding.
2. You can pass arguments to `yield`. The arguments you pass are the block local variables. For example in:

   [1,2,3].each {|x| puts x}

   `yield` is called with one of the array elements on every iteration. Calling `yield` with an argument is the same as `block.call(a)` where `a` is an argument.
3. If your method encounters a `yield` and there is no block given it will raise an exception. This might be correct in some cases. But if you want to have a different behavior if no block is given you can use the `block_given?` method to check it.
4. `&block` must be the last parameter in your method definition.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also do this by calling `block.call`

```
def update_steps(&block)
  block.call()
end
```