# Ruby method as a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In episode [389 of Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql), he creates a method called scope_schema which is both a method being used throughout the episode but also being passed as a block with `do`

Can any method be done as such? What does the `(*paths)` stand for? And how can I just create a method that can be a block? I looked at the `link_to` source code and noticed at the end `&block` which could make send given you can do

```
<%= link_to ....%>
```

or

```
<%= link_to ... do %>

<%end%>
```

Or am I incorrect?

Episode code:

```
after_create :create_schema

def create_schema
  connection.execute("create schema tenant#{id}")
  scope_schema do
    load Rails.root.join("db/schema.rb")
    connection.execute("drop table #{self.class.table_name}")
  end
end

def scope_schema(*paths)
  original_search_path = connection.schema_search_path
  connection.schema_search_path = ["tenant#{id}", *paths].join(",")
  yield
ensure
  connection.schema_search_path = original_search_path
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Any method can be called with a block if you define it as such.  The `link_to` code is a good example.

As for `*paths`, this is the [splat operator](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/splat_spec.rb), which basically means any number of arguments can be given to the method and will be read as the same argument - in this case `paths` - as an array.

Comment: So how come in the case of `scope_schema` doesn't have a `&block` yet used with a `do` or is that due to the splat operator?

Comment: the `yield` in the `scope_schema` method is yielding to a block - I'm sorry, I didn't understand that as being part of the question.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3066939/2128691) covers `yield` very well.

Answer (score 1):

*Can any method be done as such?*

Yes, just make a block available in the arguments list of your method:

```
def method(arg1, &block)
  # do something with arg1
  # call the block with or without arguments if a block is given:
  block.call() if block_given?
end
```

or

```
def method(arg1)
  # do somehting
  yield
end
```

Yield can receive arguments to.

*What does the (*paths) stand for?*

'*' is the splat operator, giving you access to has many arguments as you want. 
(same as in python)

*And how can I just create a method that can be a block?*

A method can  receive a block, or be called in a block, but cannot be a block. 
You can create a 'method' inside a proc, though.

```
a = ->(){ puts 'lalala' }

a.call
```