# How does yield work with a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to understand how yield works in Ruby?

```
def ablock
i = 1
j = 2
yield(i, j, 3, 4)
end

ablock do |x| puts x
end
```

This gives me an output of - 
1
2
3
4

But,

```
def ablock
i = 1
j = 2
yield(i, j, 3, 4)
end

ablock do |x,y| puts x, y
end
```

Gives me only 
1
2
as the output. Why don't 3 & 4 print?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby

Comment: I do not see the same results as you for the first example. When I run it with irb only see `1` printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. You have defined your block method correctly but when you go to give it a code block you only give it one variable to hold 4 objects. Instead, try giving it a variable for each object you are yielding!

```
def ablock
    i=1
    j=2
    yield(i,j,3,4)
end

ablock do |i,j,k,l|
    puts i
    puts j
    puts k
    puts l
end
```

If you would only like to use one variable in your code block you have to do multiple yield statements(one for each object).

```
def ablock
  i=1
  j=2
  yield(i)
  yield(j)
  yield(3)
  yield(4)
end

ablock do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Happy coding!

Comment: You are right! It seems the online interpreter I was using was faulty. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Mind if I ask which website you were using?

Comment: It was this one - http://repl.it/