# How this output is achieved?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby.
I found this code while reading a tutorial

```
10.times { |i | print i, " " } # o/p => 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I know times repeat a action number of times it's called.
I assume that i gets initialised to 0.
But, how it's getting incremented?

Comment: The `times` method does the incrementing. `times` is a method for the integer object, in this case, `10`, and it accepts a block as an argument (the `{...}` part) that it executes inside a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, I need another clarification. if times is an integer object and it gets increments every time how 3.times{puts "Hi!"}. prints Hi! Hi! Hi?

Comment: Why don't you check in `times` method source:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times

Comment: `times` is not an integer object. It is a *method` for the integer object. In Ruby, numbers are objects, meaning they are a class with methods. `times` is one of those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that i gets initialised to 0. But, how it's getting incremented?

There's an internal variable, the integer itself doesn't change. Let's implement our own `times` method using a basic `while` loop:

```
class Integer
  def my_times
    i = 0            # initialize to 0
    while i < self   # self is the integer object, i.e. 10
      yield i        # pass i to the block
      i += 1         # increment i
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
10.my_times { |i| print i, " " } #=> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The Ruby method is more complex (returning an enumerator without a block), but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

`times` creates an array of incrementing numbers (well an Enumerator actually, but it can be converted to an array with `to_a`)

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> 3.times.to_a
=> [0, 1, 2]
irb(main):002:0> 10.times.to_a
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times

`each` is an Array/Enumerator method that [yields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby) each element.

See:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each

Comment: Nitpicking, but it doesn't create an array (`to_a` does), it just passes each number to the block. An enumerator is only returned if no block is given.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, everything is an object, including numbers. The integers are objects, meaning, they are defined from an *Integer class* that contains methods. Those methods can be called on an instance of the object. Thus, the number `10` is an instance object of the *Integer* class and you can call methods on it.

One of those methods is *times*. When you do:

```
10.times ...
```

You are calling the `times` *method* on the *object* `10`. This method accepts a block parameter `{...}`:

```
10.times { |i| puts i }
```

Here, the `i` is the parameter for the *block* and the `times` method internally has a loop that runs that parameter from `0` to the object integer you called the *times* method on.

As @MarekLipka said in a comment, see the documentation for the [Ruby Integer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html) class.