# How "each" and "inject(symbol)" methods works in the below code?

Tags: ruby, iteration, symbols

I am not able to understand the logic of this code:

```
class VowelFinder
  include Enumerable
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def each
    @string.scan(/[aeiou]/) do |vowel|
      yield vowel
    end
  end
end

vf = VowelFinder.new("the quick brown fox jumped")
vf.inject(:+) # => "euiooue"
```

1. How is the object `vf.inject(:+)` calling the method `each` in this program?
2. How does the `each` method work in this program, because there is no block argument mentioned in function definition?
3. If I simply call `vf.each`, why am I getting the following error?

   ```
   vowel_finder.rb:8:in `block in each': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
   from vowel_finder.rb:8:in `scan'
   from vowel_finder.rb:8:in `each'
   from vowel_finder.rb:13:in `<main>'
   ```

One of the few things that I understood is that the `each` method in this class overrides the `each` method from the included `Enumerable` module. Other than that I did not understand anything about `each` and blocks.

Could someone please explain me the logic and how it works internally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocks and yields in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby)

Comment: May be going through the article [Building Enumerable & Enumerator in Ruby](https://www.practicingruby.com/articles/building-enumerable-and-enumerator) will make things clear

Answer (score 1):

The `inject` method comes from the `Enumerable` class, which is included in `VowelFinder`.  As part of the implementation of `inject`, it calls a method called `each`.

`inject` expects that the object that it's called on has an `each` method defined, as `Enumerable` does *not* provide an `each` method.  Typically, `inject` is called on instances of container classes, such as `Array` and `Hash`, which do define `each` in terms of their container design.

Thus, when `vf.inject(:+)` calls `each`, it ends up calling `VowelFinder#each`, the object being operated on is `vf` and `each` is defined on `VowelFinder`.

In Ruby, you can declare a method that implicitly accepts a block, as `each` does.  Technically, all methods in Ruby accept a block, but only *some* methods *call* a block.  The `yield` statement is used to call the block.

Ruby has a built-in function called `block_given?` that's used to detect whether a block has been passed to the method.  Many of the methods on `Array` and `Hash` use `block_given?` to determine whether to call the block or return an `Enumerator`.  Checking `block_given?` allows the block to be called conditionally, like so:

```
def each
  if block_given?
    @string.scan(/[aeiou]/) do |vowel|
      yield vowel
    end
  else
    # Do something interesting here, or better yet, return an Enumerator
  end
end
```

In this case, `each` may be called this way:

```
vf = VowelFinder.new("the quick brown fox jumped")
vf.each {|vowel| puts "Found the vowel: #{vowel}" }
```

or this way:

```
vf.each
```

The `else` in the `VowelFinder#each` method is left for a learning exercise to return an enumerator, as is the convention.

The [Enumerators and Enumerables](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/44-collections/lessons/96-enumerators-and-enumerables) chapter at [RubyMonk](https://rubymonk.com/) has very good coverage of this topic.