# Ruby passing arbitrary function and parameters into another function

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to learn Ruby.  I want to pass an arbitrary function and an arbitrary list of arguments and keyword arguments into another function.

for example, I have this arbitrary function below

```
def dummy_func(a, b)
   return a+b
end
```

And I have this wrapper function

```
def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs)
    func(args, kwargs))
end
```

I want it so I can pass my arguments in any of the following ways and still return the correct answer

```
wrapper(dummy_func, a=1, b=2)
wrapper(dummy_func, 1, b=2)
wrapper(dummy_func, a=1, b=2)
wrapper(dummy_func, 1, 2)
```

Is this possible in Ruby?  What would be an idiomatic way of approaching it?

Comment: There's no idiomatic way of doing this, because it's not a very good idea. You're producing a function that is difficult to implement, difficult to consume, and difficult to test, for no real benefit. What if somebody invokes `dummy_func(1, 2, a: 3, b: 4)`? You should have exactly one way of specifying each argument, not two.

Comment: In Ruby `f(a=1, b=2)` does not pass in arguments named `a` and `b` like in Python. It assigns values to variables named `a` and `b` while passing those arguments in as if `f(1,2)`. The keyword argument notation is `f(a: 1, b: 2)`. What's the purpose of this wrapper function? It seems like it's going to create a whole lot of ambiguity without providing any real benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to instead [yield to a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby#3066939).

```
def dummy_func(a, b, key:)
   return a+b+key
end

def wrapper
  puts yield
end

a = 4
b = 5
c = 6
wrapper do
  dummy_func(a ,b, key: c)
end
```

Since the block is closure it can see all the same variables that the call to `wrapper` can. Now there's no need to pass wrapper's arguments through.

---

If you really want to make your wrapper, you can do [some introspection to determine what arguments the wrapped function takes](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-parameters).

```
def dummy_func(a, b=23, key: 42)
   return a+b+key
end

def no_keys(a, b=23)
   return a+b
end

def wrapper(func, *array, **hash)
  method = self.method(func)
  takes_array = method.parameters.any? { |p| [:req, :opt, :rest].include?(p[0]) }
  takes_hash = method.parameters.any? { |p| [:keyreq, :key, :keyrest].include?(p[0]) }
  
  if takes_array && takes_hash
    self.send(func, *array, **hash)
  elsif takes_array
    self.send(func, *array)
  elsif takes_hash
    self.send(func, **hash)
  else
    self.send(func)
  end
end

a = 4
b = 5
c = 6
puts wrapper(:dummy_func, a, b, key:c)
puts wrapper(:no_keys, a, b)
```

But this is quite a bit more complex and less flexible than yielding to a block. This also limits you to "functions" which are really [methods on the main object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby#917842) (there are no function references in Ruby). That's why they're called with `self.send`. Blocks require no assumptions about what is being wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is keyword arguments:

https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/fun-with-keyword-arguments/

```
def hello_message(greeting, time_of_day, first_name:, last_name:)
  "#{greeting} #{time_of_day}, #{first_name} #{last_name}!"
end

args = ["Morning"]
keyword_args = {last_name: "Weiss"}

hello_message("Good", *args, first_name: "Justin", **keyword_args)
=> "Good Morning, Justin Weiss!"
```